# Checking divisibility of numbers

Tags: python, optimization, python-3.x, modulus

This comes from a [math.se post](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1499456) here. I am checking if `2^(n-1)+3` is divisible by n. This is the code I wrote,

```
def ck(n):
    c=pow(2,n-1,n)+3
    return not c%n

for i in range(10**7,2*10**7):
    if ck(i):
        print(i)
        break

print('Search Complete')
```

The function `ck` first computes `2^(n-1)%n` with the buit-in `pow`, adds 3 and finally gets the remainder. Mathematically, this is the same as `(2^(n-1)+3)%n` but substantially faster because calculating `pow(a,b,c)` is faster than `pow(a,b)%c`

I was wondering **if there are other optimizations I can make** (either in the function or in the for loop)?

The values in `range(10**7,2*10**7)` are just dummy values that I am increasing step by step so that the search doesn't go out of hand.

[Before someone gets the wrong idea, I am totally *not* cracking a hash]

Comment: i'd suggest doing, `xrange` instead of `range` for such a large range

Comment: If you are using integers only you could use a simple bitshift to achieve a square instead of calling the pow function.

Comment: @sshashank124 python 3. `range` returns an iterator.

Comment: @TimCastelijns actually `pow(2,123456789,1000)` is faster than `(2<<123456788)%1000`

Comment: @Sabyasachi, Ah I see. I missed the python-3.x tag. Couldn't you do the following then: start with `i=10**7` and then using a while loop at the end of every loop do `i *= 2` and when you are passing in the parameters to `ck` just do `ck(i+3)`.

Comment: @sshashank124 `pow(a,b,c)` is faster than `pow(a,b)%c` or `a**b%c`

Comment: for instance `pow(1234567890,2345678901,13)` returns `12` *instantly*

Comment: @Sabyasachi i just wrote a quick test and `(2<<123456788)%1000` was 5x faster in the worst case

Comment: @TimCastelijns really? it was slower for me. I tested too. weird. did you do it in a variable(`(x<<123456788)%1000`)or just `(2<<12345678)%1000`. I did the latter,

Comment: I can't imagine it being slower, there is no faster way to square an integer than performing a simple << bitshift

Comment: @TimCastelijns the squaring itself is faster. i think it is winning out due to the `%`. On my machine at least. `pow(a,b,c)` doesn't actually calculate `a^b`

Comment: I tested for the latter, too, weird indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried several different modifications to @ch3ka's answer and this is the fastest version I found.

I maintain [gmpy2](https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) so I used it for the numerical calculations. gmpy2 uses the GMP multiple-precision library and is frequently faster that using Python's native integer type. Using `gmpy2.powmod(...)` is much faster than `pow(...)`.

From the link to the original question, it is required that `gcd(i,30) == 1`. So next I tried using `gmpy2.gcd(...)` to eliminate the values for i that are impossible. This cut the running time roughly in half.

I then eliminated the call to `gmpy2.gcd(...)` by making seven passes through the range. This cut the running time roughly in half again. Lastly, I used `concurrent.futures` to distribute the test across 4 cores.

Here is the final version:

```
import sys
import time
from gmpy2 import powmod
from concurrent import futures

BLOCKSIZE = 10**8

def blocktest(block):
    start = max(10, block * BLOCKSIZE)
    end = (block + 1) * BLOCKSIZE

    now = time.time()
    result = []
    result.extend(i for i in range(30*(start//30) + 1, end, 30) if powmod(2, i-1, i) == i-3)
    result.extend(i for i in range(30*(start//30) + 7, end, 30) if powmod(2, i-1, i) == i-3)
    result.extend(i for i in range(30*(start//30) + 11, end, 30) if powmod(2, i-1, i) == i-3)
    result.extend(i for i in range(30*(start//30) + 13, end, 30) if powmod(2, i-1, i) == i-3)
    result.extend(i for i in range(30*(start//30) + 17, end, 30) if powmod(2, i-1, i) == i-3)
    result.extend(i for i in range(30*(start//30) + 19, end, 30) if powmod(2, i-1, i) == i-3)
    result.extend(i for i in range(30*(start//30) + 23, end, 30) if powmod(2, i-1, i) == i-3)
    result.extend(i for i in range(30*(start//30) + 29, end, 30) if powmod(2, i-1, i) == i-3)

    return (start, end - 1, time.time() - now, result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("starting time: ", time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        for s, e, t, r in executor.map(blocktest, range(10)):
            print("range({:,}, {:,}) time: {} et: {:6.2f} {!r}".format(s, e, time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), t, r))
```

Testing to 10**9 takes approximately 1 minute 15 seconds. It took just over 16 minutes to find the first successful value: 13957196317.

Comment: so 13957196317 is the first successful value? Great. :D

Comment: @Sabyasachi There are no other solutions less than 300,000,000,000.

Comment: whoa dude, slow down. you don't have to go all math-fu on this. :P I was looking for the smallest, smallest found. *phew* you can check the [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1499456) there is another candidate found, this `13957196317` was already predicted without brute forcing, we weren't sure if it was the *smallest*. Turns out math is better than brute force after all.

Comment: @Sabyasachi I was mostly interested in testing the multi-core scaling on a couple of different CPU architectures. I just let it run overnight on a server.

Answer (score 1):

This version is slightly faster, because we're dropping the function call overhead here:

```
print(next(i for i in range(lowerbound,upperbound) if not (pow(2,i-1,i)+3)%i), 'Search Complete')
```

That will give a ~10% speedup by my quick&dirty measurements:

```
python /tmp/so1.py  46.54s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 46.558 total
```

vs

```
python /tmp/so2.py  52.50s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 52.530 total
```

I also tried if not casting the result of `%` to bool, but testing object identity with `0` would be faster - but it is not.

Comment: well, there is always the option of going for C... but with plain python, I doubt you can do much faster (and still bruteforce it).

Comment: yes. There isn't much to search either. Since I am looking for the smallest n, and by purely number theoretic methods, we already have a solution around 1.3x10^11

Comment: So I just need to exhaust that. Also no solutions till 2^31 - 1

Comment: You can improve the performance by using gmpy2. gmpy2 provides access to the very fast GMP library. By replacing `pow(...)` with `gmpy2.powmod(...)`, I improved the performance by 50%.